# PHP File upload

Tags: php

I used the search form and I didn't find any similar post, so please bear with me.

I'm coding a script to get a directory name as input, scan the directory for files, validate the file(s)(extension, e.t.c) and upload the files to a web server. I have finished coding the script(I used ftp_put, I know I can use cURL too).

The issue now is, the script works fine on my localhost. But then, I remembered the script will be hosted online, then I have to figure how to resolve the path where the files to be uploaded will be taken from (I mean it's not like I can type C:/blahblah as the directory name).

Thank you very much guys. In anticipation.

Comment: Make that path configure-able. Then you don't need to change the code, but only the configuration. Inject the configuration into the function where you need to process files.

Comment: use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: @hakre, thx for ur prompt reply, but I don't understand what you are saying. On my localhost, I can call the function like `code` scanFolder("directoryname"); `code`. My problem now is calling the function same way above on a web server will result in the folder on the server being scanned and not the users.

Comment: @Umar Are you able to scan a local folder _outside_ of your web server?

Answer (score 1):

As an example with configuration: On the server you only need to change the configuration file according to your needs:

config.php:

```
return array(
    'upload-folder' => 'path to folder',
);
```

The rest of your script should run then based on configuration, not on hard-encoded "directoryname" values:

```
$config = include('config.php'); # load configuration data

...

process_upload($directory)
{
    ...
    scanFolder($directory);
    ...
}
```

...

```
process_upload($config['upload-folder']); # inject directory dependency
```

Hope that makes the idea more clear. It's just an example, you can do this in various ways, the important part is that you make your script work independent from the values that change by using variables.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make myself clear enough. The problem is in the upload $directory variable not the upload-folder. I mean how do I resolve a user's local directory from the internet without it resolving to the directory(if it exists) on the server.

Comment: What is "a user's local directory"? Are you referring to some specific operating system?

Comment: @Umar Are you wanting to scan a users local computer directory from your remote web server?

Comment: @hakre, thank you very much for your time and patience. I want a user to just type in the complete path to a folder (say, C:\xampp\xxx\xxx\xx\xxx\AADB1234). Then I scan that directory and upload whatever I find there. Listening to myself now, I'm not so sure it's possible. Any thoughts?

Comment: That folder is on the users computer? Or on the server?

Comment: @w3d, yes, is it possible or I'm just dumb?

Comment: @hakre, yes, it's on the user's computer.

Comment: @Umar you can't scan an arbitrary folder on the local machine from a remote web server. Apart from the security implication, how would you distinguish between C:\xampp\... on one machine and C:\xampp\... on the machine next door? If you are running a web server locally then you could establish a server to server (FTP?) connection perhaps?

Comment: @w3d, thank you very much for the explanation. You have any idea of how I can scan a directory and upload it's contents(presumable many and large) to a server from an online app.

Comment: @Umar Farouq Khattab: Please edit your question and actually ask for that. You question was totally unclear about that. You will get much better answers then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` or the `__FILE__` constant to get the filename of the current script. Then create a relative path from there using the function `dirname`.